# Unmarshalling JSON with Duplicate Fields

Tags: json, go

I'm still learning the go language, but I've been trying to find some practical things to work on to get a better handle on it. Currently, I'm trying to build a simple program that goes to a youtube channel and returns some information by taking the public JSON and unmarshalling it.

Thus far I've tried making a completely custom struct that only has a few fields in it, but that doesn't seem to pull in any values. I've also tried using tools like https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/ and getting the "real" struct that way. The issue with that method is there are numerous duplicates and I don't know enough to really assess how to tackle that.

**This is an example JSON (I apologize for its size) https://pastebin.com/6u0b39tU**

**This is the struct that I get from the above tool: https://pastebin.com/3ZCu96st**

the basic pattern of code I've tried is:

```
jsonFile, err := os.Open("test.json")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Couldn't open file", err)
}
defer jsonFile.Close()

bytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)

var channel Autogenerated

json.Unmarshal(bytes, &Autogenerated)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Failed to Unmarshal", err)
}

fmt.Println(channel.Fieldname)
```

Any feedback on the correct approach for how to handle something like this would be great. I get the feeling I'm just completely missing something.

Comment: please show a complete example.   specifically I need to see the definition of your struct.  also, duplicate fields are out fo the json spec.

Comment: If you take the pastebin file and put it into here - https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/ it spits out the struct I've been working with. I've tried both styles that the tool offers, no luck with either I'm afraid. (I tried to put it into the question, but the character length is too long!)

Comment: json.Unmarshal(bytes, &[structname]) error is not being read here ( add the error variable to identify the error your facing err = json.Unmarshal(bytes, &[structname])).. and just a suggestion try unmarshalling the json to map[string]interface{} and parse it individually

Comment: @SivaGuru I'm not exactly sure what you mean, could you give me an example of how that looks? (I am a total novice, just going through some courses with go at the moment so I apologize!)

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/woFMgfYRdcq

Comment: Thanks @SivaGuru, I'll tinker with this a bit and see if I can learn a thing or two. Appreciate the input! :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are not unmarshaling into the `channel` variable. Furthermore, you can optimize your code to not use `ReadAll`. Also, don't forget to check for errors (all errors).

Here is an improvement to your code.

```golang
jsonFile, err := os.Open("test.json")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("could not open file: %v", err)
}
defer jsonFile.Close()

var channel Autogenerated
if err := json.NewDecoder(jsonFile).Decode(&channel); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("failed to parse json: %v", err)
}

fmt.Println(channel.Fieldname)
```

Notice how a reference to `channel` is passed to `Decode`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm primarily learning from various internet guides as I dip my toes into go so I don't yet have a firm grasp of what the "right" way to do things are. I appreciate pointing out the optimization!